# Flask/SQLAlchemy error: TypeError: Incompatible collection type: unicode is not list-like

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I am getting this error during inserting data in many to many relationship in sqlalchemy.
Models.py

```
class Event(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'event'
id = db.Column(db.String(255), primary_key=True)
title = db.Column(db.String(255))
image_url = db.Column(db.String(255))
category_id = db.Column(db.String(255), db.ForeignKey('category.id'),
                        nullable=True)
subheading = db.Column(db.String(255))
event_city = db.Column(db.String(255))
venue = db.Column(db.String(255))
start_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
end_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
description = db.Column(db.String(255))
speaker = db.relationship("Speaker",
                          secondary=association_table)
errors = {}

def __init(self, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
    speaker1 = db.session.query(Speaker).first()
    print speaker
    self.speaker.append(speaker1)
    self.id = generate_id()
    kwargs.pop(EVENT_FIELDS['EVENT_SPEAKER'])
    kwargs.pop(EVENT_FIELDS['EVENT_CATEGORY'])
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        try:
            setattr(self, key, value)
        except ex:
            Event.errors = FORM_EMPTY_FIELD.format(key)
```

association table is

```
association_table = db.Table('association',
                         db.Column('speaker_id', db.String(255),
                                   db.ForeignKey('speaker.id')),
                         db.Column('event_id', db.String(255),
                                   db.ForeignKey('event.id')))
```

when i am inserting data i am getting error as mention above

Comment: What's the data you're attempting to insert look like?

Answer (score 0):

In a M2M relationship the association in the speaker column of your model Event must be passed as list (means between brackets []) in this way, please note in `__init__` method the assignation of speaker  :

```
def __init(self, **kwargs):
    print kwargs
    speaker1 = db.session.query(Speaker).first()
    print speaker
    self.speaker = [speaker1]
    self.id = generate_id()
    kwargs.pop(EVENT_FIELDS['EVENT_SPEAKER'])
    kwargs.pop(EVENT_FIELDS['EVENT_CATEGORY'])
    for key, value in kwargs.iteritems():
        try:
            setattr(self, key, value)
        except ex:
            Event.errors = FORM_EMPTY_FIELD.format(key)
```